# Trouble with converting JS to cheerio

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, request, cheerio

I am using cheerio to web scrape. I am able to get the values I need with the code below in the browser. Problem I am having is converting this into cheerio because I need to parse using requests. I personally find the cheerio documentation kind of confusing and what I have tried hasn't worked. If anyone can help me converting this to cheerio that would be greatly appreciated.

```
let lol = JSON.parse(document.querySelector('#maincontent > script:nth-child(5)').innerHTML.split('{"variants":')[1].split(`};`)[0])
lol.forEach((res)=>{
if(res.width == 'D'){
if(res.style == 'M1080W11'){
console.log(res)
}
}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You would replace this:

```
document.querySelector('#maincontent > script:nth-child(5)').innerHTML
```

with:

```
$('#maincontent > script:nth-child(5)').text()
```